# Xcode Archiving: The following errors occurred while locating and generating signing assets

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, entitlements, iosdeployment

I don't have any warnings/errors in xcode, but when I try to archive and distribute my app, I get the following:

> Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the
>   "ThisOrThat.app" target's entitlements. Switch to manual signing and
>   resolve the issue by downloading a matching provisioning profile from
>   the developer website. Alternatively, to continue using automatic
>   signing, remove these entitlements from your entitlements file and
>   their associated functionality from your code. Then rebuild your
>   archive and try again.
>
> Provisioning profile failed qualification Profile doesn't match the
>   entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.

I am using associated domains and push notifications for capabilities. My entitlements file has APS Environment and Associated Domains.

I have tried deleting provisioning profiles, deleting entitlement, deleting derived data, turning different capabilities on and off, and turning on and off manual signing.

Can't figure out what the problem is

Comment: Either your manual certificate is not valid/doesn't match with profile Or if you choose Automatic then limit of number of certificates has been reached. So check with the developer account if there is option to create more certificate or ask your colleague to provide you `.p12` of already generated certificate.

Comment: You need to create `the specific bundle id` of you app  on website and enable `push notification` on website. 

Then you can do all `Automatic signing` stuff in Xcode.